# Toda Flow Embeddings

Tags: differential-equations, integrable-systems, eigenvalues

What are strategies for generating the following types of pictures:
[image]

Here's what's going on here. Take a toda flow in 3 variables. The equations of motion are:

$$\frac{d}{dt}a_k=2(b_k^2-b_{k-1}^2),$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}b_k=b_k(a_{k+1}-a_k),$$

where $a_i,b_i>0$, which can be represented as a commutator involving the matrix $L(a,b)$, which is a tridiagonal matrix with $a_i$ on the diagonal and $b_i$ on the superdiagonals. The hexagon above incorporates the following phenomenon of the Toda flow of $L(a,b)$:

[image]

where the edges and vertices are labeled by the structure of the $L$ matrix there.
My question is, what are the possible ways of giving this hexagon a sense of distance (thus being able to draw Toda flow trajectories). Essentially this should somehow depend on the relative size of $a_i,b_i$'s, how close $a_i$ is to a particular eigenvalue, etc. For example, the $b_i$ are all exponentially decreasing, so it seems like one needs to look at ratios of $b_i$ to conclude which side of the hexagon we are closer to. This still seems very arbitrary and results in singularities at the boundary (which in higher dimensions become an issue since Toda flows perfectly well cross over such boundaries).

I know that the $n$ dimensional Toda flow is diffeomorphic to the $n-1$ sphere via looking at the vector $(u_{11},u_{12},\ldots,u_{1n})$ of normalized first-components of the corresponding eigenvectors of $L$. Is it as simple as projecting these onto the embedded permutahedron? Here's the picture for $n=4$,

[image]

> What is a good coordinate system to draw these trajectories on the hexagon/permutahedron?

Reference:
[ODE's and the Symmetric Eigenvalue Problem](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~tt249057/other/2157167.pdf)

Comment: The sets $b_j=0$ are of course invariant. This seems to contradict some of your remarks, but probably I am misinterpreting them.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: you're right but for higher dimensions you inevitably have to exit each face, and this is where the difficulty arises. See for example figure 7 of the above reference.

Comment: It seems like you might be asking the following question: Let $X$ be the set of tridiagonal symmetric matrices with spectrum $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)$ and off diagonal elements nonnegative. Let $\delta: X \to \mathbb{R}^3$ take a tridiagonal matrix to its diagonal. Is this map a bijection onto the hexagon? The answer appears to be no! Suppose the spectrum is $(3, -1, -2)$. Then $(0,0,0)$ is in the hexagon. But a tridiagonal matrix with diagonal $(0,0,0)$ always has determinant $0$, so can't have spectrum $(3,-1,-2)$.

Comment: I am very puzzled trying to visualize what $\delta(X)$ does look like. Since $X$ is compact, $\delta(X)$ is closed, so there must be some open neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$ missing. And the paper you link says that $X$ is a toplogical disc. I don't have a contradiction, but this is confusing.

Comment: Working on it a bit more: If we ask for $\begin{pmatrix} a & x & 0 \\ x & -a-b & y \\ 0 & y & b \end{pmatrix}$ to have spectrum $(-3,1,2)$, we get $x = \sqrt{(2-a)(1-a)(3+a)/(b-a)}$ and $y=\sqrt{(2-b)(1-b)(3+b)/(a-b)}$. I find that the two quantities under the square root are positive only on two rectangles: $[-3,1] \times [1,2]$ and $[1,2] \times [-3,1]$. So $\delta(X)$ forms a "bow tie" in the hexagon. Moreover, there is a hole line segment of $X$ collapsed to the point $(1,1)$. So $\delta$ is not at all a homeomorphism.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: I believe one assumes that $a_i,b_i>0$ and so the Toda flow then preserves positivity. I've added this detail, thank you! I've also added the 4-d toda flow picture.

Comment: Assuming that the $a_i$ are positive doesn't help; you can always add a large multiple of the identity. So tridiagonal matrices with spectrum $(7,11,12)$ would have diagonal missing a neighborhood of $(10,10,10)$, just as tridiagonal matrices with spectrum $(-3,1,2)$ missed a neighborhood of $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Your $\delta$ is not the map studied in the linked paper. Rather, $J\in X$ gets mapped to the first components of the eigenvectors (it's really better though to view this as the vector $\rho(\{\lambda_j\})$, where $\rho$ is the "natural" spectral measure).

Comment: @ChristianRemling If I understood the paper correctly, that makes a map to a spherical triangle (and three of the edges of the hexagon get collapsed to points). I think Alex R's question was how to naturally get hexagonal coordinates on $X$. The map $\delta$ seemed the obvious approach, so it was interesting to me that it didn't work. I might have misunderstood the question, though.

Comment: Elaborating on this, it is pretty obvious (given some background in this kind of inverse spectral theory, that is) that this map identifies $X$ with a "hexagon" (why not call it a disk, though??). A Jacobi matrix with prescribed spectrum is determined by also choosing three weights in the spectral measure that satisfy $w_1+w_2+w_3=1$, $w_j\ge 0$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Well, the obvious reason to draw it as a hexagon is that there are six special points on the boundary (the diagonal matrices). Indeed, I'm curious: Where are these six points in the $w_i$ coordinates? I think the original poster's question (which I have not answered) is what coordinate system on the hexagon is being used to draw flow diagrams like the first figure.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: Actually, what I wrote is not completely correct. The parametrization by the $w_j$'s works if $b_k>0$, and then $w_j>0$. The degenerate cases (when $e_1$ is not cyclic) need to be looked at separately (I don't think it can be difficult).

Comment: @DavidSpeyer: I am indeed interested in the coordinate system on the hexagon. I've added this as emphasis to the question.

Comment: I think that, geometrically, this hexahedron is the image of the moment map from the flag manifold $\mathcal{F}$ of complete flags of 3-space to the traceless 3x3 matrices, where the Toda flow comes from the action of the diagonal matrix A in $\mathcal{F}$ (actually, action of exp(tA) or looking at A as induced vector field). The tridiagonal matrices form an invariant manifold and it seems that the moment map restricted to them is a diffeomorphism: maybe one can get more concrete coordinates from this.
I can try to find some references for this if you think it is a direction worth pursuing.